# Reset R instance

Tags: r

Is it possible to reset an instance of R?

Eg. if I have used the commands

```
x <- 1:10
plot(x, -x)
```

And thus polluted the system with the x variable. In this state can I then revert back to a clean state without shutting R down and launching it again?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can remove all variables from your workspace using

```
rm(list = ls())
```

You can 'unload' packages with

```
detach(package:packagename)
```

---

EDIT:

You can close all graphics devices with

```
graphics.off()
```

You can clear the command editor history with `CTRL+L`.

If you use Tinn-R as your editor, there is a 'Clear all' button, which clears your workspace and command editor history, and closes graphics devices.  (It does not detach packages.)

---

ANOTHER EDIT:

One other thing that you would have to do to reset R is to close all open connections.  It is incredibly bad form to leave open connections lying about, so this is more [belt and braces](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/61250.html) than a necessity.  <del>(You can probably fool `close_all_connections` by opening connections in obscure environments, but in that case you have only yourself to blame.)</del>

```
is.connection <- function(x) inherits(x, "connection")

get_connections <- function(envir = parent.frame()) 
{
  Filter(is.connection, mget(ls(envir = envir), envir = envir))
}

close_all_connections <- function() 
{
   lapply(c(sys.frames(), globalenv(), baseenv()), 
      function(e) lapply(get_connections(e), close))
}

close_all_connections()
```

As Marek suggests, use `closeAllConnections` to do this.

ANOTHER EDIT:

In response to Ben's comment about resetting options, that's actually a little bit tricky.  the best way to do it would be to store a copy of your options when you load R, and then reset them at this point.

```
#on R load
assign(".Options2", options(), baseenv())

#on reset
options(baseenv()$.Options2)
```

If you aren't foresighted enough to set this up when you load R, then you need something like this function.

```
reset_options <- function()
{
  is_win <- .Platform$OS.type == "windows"
  options(
    add.smooth            = TRUE,
    browserNLdisabled     = FALSE,
    CBoundsCheck          = FALSE,
    check.bounds          = FALSE,
    continue              = "+ ",
    contrasts             = c(
      unordered = "contr.treatment", 
      ordered   = "contr.poly"
    ), 
    defaultPackages       = c(
      "datasets", 
      "utils", 
      "grDevices", 
      "graphics", 
      "stats",
      "methods"
    ),  
    demo.ask              = "default",
    device                = if(is_win) windows else x11,
    device.ask.default    = FALSE,
    digits                = 7,
    echo                  = TRUE,
    editor                = "internal",
    encoding              = "native.enc",
    example.ask           = "default",
    expressions           = 5000,
    help.search.types     = c("vignette", "demo", "help"),    
    help.try.all.packages = FALSE,
    help_type             = "text",
    HTTPUserAgent         = with(
      R.version, 
      paste0(
        "R (", 
        paste(major, minor, sep = "."), 
        " ", 
        platform, 
        " ", 
        arch, 
        " ", 
        os, 
        ")"
      )
    ),
    internet.info         = 2,
    keep.source           = TRUE,
    keep.source.pkgs      = FALSE,
    locatorBell           = TRUE,
    mailer                = "mailto",
    max.print             = 99999,
    menu.graphics         = TRUE,
    na.action             = "na.omit",
    nwarnings             = 50,
    OutDec                = ".",
    pager                 = "internal",
    papersize             = "a4",
    pdfviewer             = file.path(R.home("bin"), "open.exe"),
    pkgType               = if(is_win) "win.binary" else "source",
    prompt                = "> ",
    repos                 = c(
      CRAN      = "@CRAN@", 
      CRANextra = "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"
    ), 
    scipen                = 0,
    show.coef.Pvalues     = TRUE,
    show.error.messages   = TRUE,
    show.signif.stars     = TRUE,
    str                   = list(
      strict.width = "no",
      digits.d     = 3,
      vec.len      = 4
    ),
    str.dendrogram.last   = "`",
    stringsAsFactors      = TRUE,
    timeout               = 60,
    ts.eps                = 1e-05,
    ts.S.compat           = FALSE,
    unzip                 = "internal",
    useFancyQuotes        = TRUE,
    verbose               = FALSE,
    warn                  = 0,
    warning.length        = 1000,
    width                 = 80,
    windowsTimeouts       = c(100, 500)
  )
)
```

The options in that function provide a vanilla R session so you might wish to source your Rprofile.site file afterwards to customise R how you like it.

```
source(file.path(R.home("etc"), "Rprofile.site"))
```

Comment: As I understand it, there can still be devices open after using these two commands. Is there a single command that lets you reset R back to scratch. In gnuplot the "reset" command did the job.

Comment: R is a bit more complicated than gnuplot.

Comment: There is `closeAllConnections` function.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  The only other things I'd add are: 1 - a call to `gc(reset = TRUE)`, perhaps several times just to be sure, and 2 - `unlink` for any tempfiles and the contents of `tempdir`.

Comment: how about resetting `options()` ... ?

Comment: Note problems with registered S3 methods that are not reset by a detach discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11004018/892313

Comment: @BrianDiggs: OK, I give up.  I can't think of any scenario in which programmatically trying to reset R is easier than closing and reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the response of @Richie Cotton, comments and more, I think it's worth to consider five elements:

1. Remove all objects
2. Unload non-native packages
3. Close all connections
4. Restore the default options
5. Close all graphic devices

So, there it is my simple `ResetR` function:

```
ResetR = function() {

    # 1) Remove all objects
    rm(list = ls(all=TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)

    # 2) Unload non-native packages. 
    nat = c(".GlobalEnv", "package:datasets", "package:evd", "package:nortest", "package:MASS", "package:stats", "package:graphics", "package:grDevices", "package:utils", "package:methods", "Autoloads", "package:base")

    p = search()
    for (i in p) {
        if (is.na(match(i, nat))) {
            try(eval(parse(text=paste0("detach(", i, ", unload=T, force=T)"))), silent=T) # force=T is need in case package has dependency
        }
    }

    # 3) Close all connections
    try(closeAllConnections(), silent=T)

    # 4) Restore default options
    try(options(baseenv()$.Options2), silent=T) # Remember to put assign(".Options2", options(), baseenv()) at the bottom of YOUR_R_HOME\etc\Rprofile.site

    # 5) Close all graphic devices
    graphics.off()

}
```

hth