# How can a non-imported method in a not-attached package be found by calls to functions not having it in their namespace?

Tags: r, namespaces, scoping

An R namespace acts as the immediate environment for all functions in its associated package. In other words, when function `bar()` from package **foo** calls another function, the R evaluator first searches for the other function in `<environment: namespace:foo>`, then in `"imports.foo"`, `<environment: namespace:base>`, `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`, and so on down the search list returned by typing `search()`.

One nice aspect of namespaces is that they can make packages act like better citizens: unexported functions in `<environment: namespace:foo>` and functions in `imports:foo` are available only: (a) to functions in **foo**; (b) to other packages that import from **foo**; or (c) via fully qualified function calls like `foo:::bar()`.

Or so I thought until recently...

### The behavior

[This recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939516/data-frame-transformation-gives-different-results-when-same-code-is-run-before-a/10940237#10940237) highlighted a case in which a function well-hidden in its package's namespace was nonetheless found by a call to a seemingly unrelated function:

```
group <- c("C","F","D","B","A","E")
num <- c(12,11,7,7,2,1)
data <- data.frame(group,num)

## Evaluated **before** attaching 'gmodels' package
T1 <- transform(data, group = reorder(group,-num))

## Evaluated **after** attaching 'gmodels
library(gmodels)
T2 <- transform(data, group = reorder(group,-num))

identical(T1, T2) 
# [1] FALSE
```

### Its immediate cause

@Andrie answered the original question by pointing out that **gmodels** imports from the the package **gdata**, which includes a function `reorder.factor` that gets dispatched to inside the second call to `transform()`. `T1` differs from `T2` because the first is calculated by `stats:::reorder.default()` and the second by `gdata:::reorder.factor()`.

### My question

How is it that in the above call to `transform(data, group=reorder(...))`, the dispatching mechanism for `reorder` finds and then dispatches to `gdata:::reorder.factor()`?

(An answer should include an explanation of the scoping rules that lead from a call involving functions in the **stats** and **base** packages to a seemingly well-hidden method in **gdata**.)

---

### Further possibly helpful details

1. Neither `gdata:::reorder.factor`, nor the **gdata** package as a whole are explicitly imported by **gmodels**. Here are the `import*` directives in **gmodels**' **NAMESPACE** file:

   ```
   importFrom(MASS, ginv)
   importFrom(gdata, frameApply)
   importFrom(gdata, nobs)
   ```
2. There are no methods for `reorder()` or `transform()` in `<environment: namespace:gmodels>`, nor in `"imports:gmodels"`:

   ```
   ls(getNamespace("gmodels"))
   ls(parent.env(getNamespace("gmodels")))
   ```
3. Detaching **gmodels** does not revert `reorder()`'s behavior: `gdata:::reorder.factor()` still gets dispatched:

   ```
   detach("package:gmodels")
   T3 <- transform(data, group=reorder(group,-num))
   identical(T3, T2)
   # [1] TRUE
   ```
4. `reorder.factor()` is not stored in the list of S3 methods in the base environment:

   ```
   grep("reorder", ls(.__S3MethodsTable__.))
   # integer(0)
   ```

R chat threads from the last couple of days include some additional ideas. Thanks to Andrie, Brian Diggs, and Gavin Simpson who (with others) should feel free to edit or add possibly impt. details to this question.

Comment: I see it's your first question. Welcome to SO! :)

Comment: +1 for good stewardship of your own question.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen -- And you think that your problem was driving you batty! Figuring out what was going on here obsessed me for several days, before I realized "Oh, duh. I should ask this on SO and get some better minds working on this for me!"

Comment: I've learned to give up after 30 minutes. It's cheaper to pay people in checkmarks and upvotes :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question, but the main point is that `group` is character vector while `data$group` is factor.

After attaching `gmodels`, the call for `reorder(factor)` calls `gdata:::reorder.factor`.
so, `reorder(factor(group))` calls it.

In `transform`, the function is evaluated within the environment of the first argument, so in `T2 <- transform(data, group = reorder(group,-num))`, `group` is factor.

**UPDATED**

`library` attaches the import packages into loaded namespace.

```
> loadedNamespaces()
 [1] "RCurl"     "base"      "datasets"  "devtools"  "grDevices" "graphics"  "methods"  
 [8] "stats"     "tools"     "utils"    
> library(gmodels) # here, namespace:gdata is loaded
> loadedNamespaces()
 [1] "MASS"      "RCurl"     "base"      "datasets"  "devtools"  "gdata"     "gmodels"  
 [8] "grDevices" "graphics"  "gtools"    "methods"   "stats"     "tools"     "utils"
```

Just in case, the `reorder` generic exists in `namespace:stats`:

```
> r <- ls(.__S3MethodsTable__., envir = asNamespace("stats"))
> r[grep("reorder", r)]
[1] "reorder"            "reorder.default"    "reorder.dendrogram"
```

**And for more details**

The call of `reorder` will search the S3generics in two envs:

see `?UseMethod`

> first in the environment in which the generic function is called, and then in the registration data base for the environment in which the generic is defined (typically a namespace).

then, `loadNamespace` registers the S3 functions to the namespace.

So , in your case, `library(gmodels)` -> `loadNamespace(gdata)` -> `registerS3Methods(gdata)`.

After this, you can find it by:

```
> methods(reorder)
[1] reorder.default*    reorder.dendrogram* reorder.factor*    

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

However, as the `reorder.factor` is not attached on your search path, you cannot access it directly:

```
> reorder.factor
Error: object 'reorder.factor' not found
```

Probably this is whole scenario.

Comment: Could you explain how starting from (either of) the two environments mentioned in `?UseMethod`, a search for a function even looks in *gdata*'s Namespace? It is loaded, but I thought not on the search path (which I thought was the difference between being loaded and attached).

Comment: @BrianDiggs -- Here's what happens. When `gdata` is loaded, all of the methods that it defines are "registered" in data bases in a variety of different namespaces. The rule is that a method gets registered in the namespace of the package that defines its S3 generic. Since `reorder` is defined in **stats**, that's where it gets registered, in an environment called `.__S3MethodsTable__.`. Check this out: `library(gmodels);  head(ls(getNamespace("stats"), all=TRUE)); ls(stats:::.__S3MethodsTable__., pattern="reorder");  get("reorder.factor", stats:::.__S3MethodsTable__.)`. Cool, eh?

Comment: @BrianDiggs -- The upshot of this is that if you `importFrom()` even a single function from a package, you also register **all** of the methods in that package. (Quite an unexpected side-effect, though I can see why R-core did it that way.) This also explains why detaching gmodels had no impact on which `reorder()` method gets called: detaching does not go around and clean up all of the methods that were registered when the package was loaded. (In fact, even `unloadNamespace()` doesn't do that cleanup. I wonder if there's some function that does...)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks for the clarification. It is worth noting that `ls(.__S3MethodsTable__., envir=asNamespace("stats"))` is not the same as `ls(stats:::.__S3MethodsTable__.)` (the former in kohske's answer, the latter in your comment). The latter seems more appropriate, and shows that the method functions are loaded in the namespace of the generic without regard to the original namespace. Also, I think I have heard (but can't cite right now) that there is no way to fully guarantee a complete detachment of a package once loaded; this may be one of the reasons why.

Comment: @BrianDiggs -- True. `ls(.__S3MethodsTable__., envir=asNamespace("stats"))` is essentially just `ls(asNamespace("stats")`, since there's no `.__S3MethodsTable__.` in `.GlobalEnv`. I bet you're also right about this being a (or perhaps *the*) reason that detaching is not reliably complete.