# How to disable package without restarting R?

Tags: r, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to unload a package without restarting R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979917/how-to-unload-a-package-without-restarting-r)

To load a package into R we can go `library(.)` or `require(.)`. How do I disable a package during a coding session. I want something that's the opposite of `require(.)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6979917

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think maybe you're looking for `detach(package:splines, unload = TRUE)`.

As you might gather from the comments below, be sure to read carefully the Details section of `?detach` to make sure you know exactly what will happen when using this with or without the `unload` and `force` arguments.

Comment: note that with complicated packages that load S4 classes & methods, this unloading is not *guaranteed* to restore everything to exactly the state before the package was loaded. (There's discussion on r-devel somewhere I think ...)

Comment: In particular, if the package supplies any S3 methods whose generic is from another package, those methods won't be removed by any `detach()` call ([example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004018/how-can-a-non-imported-method-in-a-not-attached-package-be-found-by-calls-to-fun) in kohske's answer). (I'd love to know if there are any other classes of objects that can be left lying around by `detach()`.)