# Load, detach, re-load anomaly

Tags: r, data.table, rodbc

I'm attaching, detaching, and re-attaching **RODBC** and **data.table**. When I perform this process with these packages in this order, I get the following error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'data.table', details:
  call: address(x)
  error: object 'Caddress' not found
```

I'm using the latest versions of these packages. This is my initial session info:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

**Example**

```
pkgs <- c('RODBC', 'data.table') # Note, c('data.table', 'RODBC') will work
for (pkg in pkgs) library(pkg, character.only=TRUE)
for (pkg in paste0('package:', pkgs)) detach(pkg, unload=TRUE, character.only=TRUE)
for (pkg in pkgs) library(pkg, character.only=TRUE)
```

Comment: What if you detach in reverse order? `for (pkg in rev(paste0('package:', pkgs)))` I don't have all these packages installed so I am unable to try.

Comment: All other orders of the three packages work, and any 2 combinations of them also work.

Comment: detaching and reloading is never as clean in R as I would like it to be -- long-standing grumble about this aspect of the design.  That is, it seems that it's almost impossible in general to engineer code so that attaching + detaching gets you *exactly* back to the state where you started.

Comment: @BenBolker Is this a problem with the design of R or a problem with the design of the packages? Surely clean attaching + detaching should be possible.

Comment: I can't say for sure.  There may be a way to tweak the package so that it attaches/detaches cleanly.  What I can say is that it can be very difficult to do this.  The two areas where I have had problems are (1) unregistering S4 methods and (2) finalizing Rcpp objects. e.g. https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/35

Comment: And adding to @BenBolker's list of problem areas, there is also no guarantee that even an S3 method will be unregistered when the package that supplies it is detached. ([See here for an e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004018/how-can-a-non-imported-method-in-a-not-attached-package-be-found-by-calls-to-fun)) (Not that any of these necessarily explain what's going on in the case you've presented above.)

Comment: If you just do: `require(RODBC); require(data.table); pkgs <- c('RODBC','data.table'); for (pkg in paste0('package:', pkgs)) detach(pkg, unload=TRUE, character.only=TRUE); require(RODBC); require(data.table)`, this also reproduces the error - without a third package.

Comment: @Arun, thanks. I thought I had tried that, but apparently not.

Comment: Filed [#5671](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5671&group_id=240&atid=975).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This is now fixed in [commit 1332](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/c20eba451e72ff3b0c42ee7724d7fbae0870a80c) of [v1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues):

> Added a `.onUnload` method to unload `data.table`'s shared object properly. Since the name of the shared object is 'datatable.so' and not 'data.table.so', 'detach' fails to unload correctly. This was the reason for the issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498804/load-detach-re-load-anomaly) on SO. Closes [#474](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/474). Thanks to Matthew Plourde for reporting.