# How can I stop rmarkdown::render() from Rmd files inside project's renv library?

Tags: r-markdown, blogdown, renv

I have a Hugo blog which is compiled using the default `blogdown::build_site()` route.

I decided to give `renv::` a try, because some of my posts are both plot-heavy and prone to depend on old package versions, so why not make sure future complete site rebuilds won't cause problems, right? With that in mind, I decided that the best way to use `renv` was to make each blog post (in `/content/post/`) its own `renv` project. Due to the global library caching used by `renv`, this shouldn't even cause much of a storage penalty.

Now the blog won't compile because `rmarkdown::render()` (which is called by `build_site()` for each blog post) seems to traverse the entire tree of each blog post looking for Rmd files, and of course discovering some inside the `renv` library folder, happily attempting to compile them -- and predictably failing.

So my question is

- is putting each blog post under its own `renv` environment contrary to common practice (I'm just beginning to learn renv and friends)?
- if not, why is `build_site()` not playing nice with `renv`? Am I missing something? Or have I discovered a bonafide issue? Or should I just let go and switch to a [manual blogdown site-building method](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/methods.html)?

This problem seems trivial (we simply have to stop `render()` from traversing the `/renv/` directory), but as far as I can tell, this interplay between blogdown and renv seems unexplored (I've found only some tangentially [related](https://community.rstudio.com/t/renv-lockfile-per-rmarkdown-doc/48642/4) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724682/use-rmarkdownrender-in-a-restricted-environment), so I thought I could look for advice here first.

My site is built using `Rscript -e "blogdown::build_site(local=FALSE)"` (not using the button in RStudio). Once this script starts to render Rmd files inside the `renv` library tree, it eventually fails:

```
$ Rscript -e "blogdown::build_site(local=FALSE)"
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/blogdown/resources/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/01-intro.Rmd
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Defaulting to '01-intro.utf8' as the title.
  To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or --metadata title="...".
Warning message:
The label(s) intro, methods not found
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/02-literature.Rmd
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Defaulting to '02-literature.utf8' as the title.
  To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or --metadata title="...".
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/03-method.Rmd
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Defaulting to '03-method.utf8' as the title.
  To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or --metadata title="...".
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/04-application.Rmd
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Defaulting to '04-application.utf8' as the title.
  To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or --metadata title="...".
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/05-summary.Rmd
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Defaulting to '05-summary.utf8' as the title.
  To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or --metadata title="...".
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/06-references.Rmd
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Defaulting to '06-references.utf8' as the title.
  To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or --metadata title="...".
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/index.Rmd
Rendering content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/cli/doc/pluralization.Rmd
Quitting from lines 15-15 (./../man/chunks/pluralization.Rmd)
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: local ... call_block -> lapply -> FUN -> knit -> readLines -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file './../man/chunks/pluralization.Rmd': No such file or directory
Execution halted
Error in render_page(f) :
  Failed to render 'content/post/2016-11-18-notes-inorganic-chemistry/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/cli/doc/pluralization.Rmd'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> build_rmds -> render_page
Execution halted
```

Here's my sessioninfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.2  htmltools_0.4.0 tools_3.6.2     rstudioapi_0.11
 [5] yaml_2.2.1      Rcpp_1.0.4.6    rmarkdown_2.1   knitr_1.28     
 [9] digest_0.6.25   xfun_0.13       packrat_0.5.0   rlang_0.4.5    
[13] renv_0.9.3      evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the second part of my question, the `blogdown::build_site()` [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/86ea620d6dfbe0f745ad89dc131b0dc6662e572c/R/render.R) provides clear answers.

`build_site()` calls `list_rmds()`, which does the following (copied verbatim from source, easy enough to follow along):

```
list_rmds = function(dir, check = FALSE) {
  files = list.files(dir, rmd_pattern, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
  # exclude Rmd that starts with _ (preserve these names for, e.g., child docs)
  # but include _index.Rmd/.md
  files = files[!grepl('^_', basename(files)) | grepl('^_index[.]', basename(files))]
  # do not allow special characters in filenames so dependency names are more
  # predictable, e.g. foo_files/
  if (check) bookdown:::check_special_chars(files)
  files
}
```

As can be seen it lists *all* Rmd files, recursively, and then excludes Rmd files beginning with `_`.

Based on this, it is obvious why `renv::` renders Rmd files inside the renv directory. It's also clear that using `packrat::` instead wouldn't make any difference.

A way around this is of course to use a custom site build script, as mentioned in the blogdown docs, but I still wonder if the combination of blogdown and renv should not be supported by the default approach (assuming other people like to put each blogpost in its own renv project).

Comment: The [above-mentioned issue](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/451) has now been addressed and closed. The latest `blogdown::build_site()` master now includes code to avoid traversing the `renv` or `packrat` directories. I will go ahead and mark my own answer to close this question.